# Pivot Table import .sql using dev express

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pivot-table

I have a pivot table using windows form application
I want to replace the data in pivot table with import data using .sql
I have tried this code

```
private void btnSelectFile_ItemClick(object sender,DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.Filter = "Text files | *.sql";
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string fileName;
                fileName = dlg.FileName;
            }
        string ConnString = "server=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=db;persist security info=true;";

        DataTable Data = new DataTable();

        using(SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
        {
            connect.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [dataGridView1_Data$]", connect);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(Data);

            connect.Close();
        }

    }
```

but the connection error

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'

Comment: Plenty of things are wrong here. Starting with formatting, hard-coded connection string, hard-coded query, what if user presses Cancel you still proceed with running the query, improper resource cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Start by connecting to the database from visual studio directly. Your connection string looks incorrect.

```
string ConnString = "server=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=db;persist security info=true;";
```

I do not believe SQL Server allows empty passwords anymore.

Comment: I have tried to fill the password and it does not work

Comment: Do you know the password? Simply place that in your connection string.

Comment: yes absolutely I know the password, the error is still the same 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'

Comment: Have you placed that password in your connection string? It says password=; currently, which means you have no provided any password to it.

Comment: yes of course
I change to string ConnString = "server=localhost; user id=root; password=secret; database=db;persist security info=true;";

Comment: Alright, try connecting through Visual studio or SSMS application.